# How to display image in Notification send to iOS Device via firebase console in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I want to display image in push notification in flutter. I am using awesome_notification to display notification sent from backend server and notification is displayed properly with image but when notification are send from firebase console notification gets displayed with title and body but no image is displayed on iOS device. How can I do this in flutter. Any help is appreciated.

Custom Notification to display notification sent from backend server using awesome_notification

```
showImageNotification(){
    AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
            id: 10,
            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
            title: 'Simple Notification',
            body: 'Simple body',
            bigPicture: "https://res-2.cloudinary.com/linkisin/image/upload/v1648031558/linkisin/development/general_notification_message/Valentine_s-Day-CampaignPage-Mobile_nki5lx_qilwyd.jpg",
           largeIcon: "https://res-2.cloudinary.com/linkisin/image/upload/v1648031558/linkisin/development/general_notification_message/Valentine_s-Day-CampaignPage-Mobile_nki5lx_qilwyd.jpg",
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
          displayOnBackground: true,
          displayOnForeground: true,
          customSound: "notification_tone.caf",
        )
    );
```

Added NotificationExtension

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
 

        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [Hello]"
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        

        }
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}
```